# Facebook Invalid KeyHash Error when logging for second time using Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I m getting invalid key hash in the application I'm providing social media login functionality.
When I am logging first time using Facebook app installed on my device it works well but for second time it gives me invalid key hash error.

Answer (score 0):

log that key hash and add that in facebook developer

```
    private void onCreateHashKey() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "your.package",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It was an issue by facebook.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1755756591335035/?comment_id=2027873617436930